# How do I combine 2 different pieces of data to achieve one "master set"? [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, regression

This is going to be a lengthy post, so bear with me here. Before I dive into what exactly my issue is, the location to get the download file for my data can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/nathanlauga/nba-games. All you need to do once you're there is download the games.csv file.

**Explanation**

I am running a regression analysis of win probability against various statistics. You'll notice the data is split into two pieces essentially: "HOME" and "AWAY". I have made a linear model for the home team and the away team. Below is the code broken into a "HOME" part and "AWAY" part to be replicated. Note that the first part before the actual analysis is simply just replacing the ID number with the actual abbreviated names of the teams:

```
NBA_Games <- read.csv(file ="games.csv", header = T)
NBA.df <- data.frame(NBA_Games)

head(NBA.df)

NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612737"] <- "ATL"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612738"] <- "BOS"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612740"] <- "NO"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612741"] <- "CHI"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612742"] <- "DAL"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612743"] <- "DEN"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612745"] <- "HOU"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612746"] <- "LAC"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612747"] <- "LAL"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612748"] <- "MIA"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612749"] <- "MIL"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612750"] <- "MIN"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612751"] <- "BKN"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612752"] <- "NYK"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612753"] <- "ORL"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612754"] <- "IND"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612755"] <- "PHI"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612756"] <- "PHX"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612757"] <- "POR"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612758"] <- "SAC"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612759"] <- "SAS"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612760"] <- "OKC"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612761"] <- "TOR"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612762"] <- "UTA"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612763"] <- "MEM"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612764"] <- "WAS"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612765"] <- "DET"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612766"] <- "CHA"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612739"] <- "CLE"
NBA.df[NBA.df == "1610612744"] <- "GSW"


tail(NBA.df)
install.packages("dplyr")


library(dplyr)
games <- NBA.df %>%
  group_by(SEASON, TEAM_ID_home) %>%
  summarise(avg_points = mean(PTS_home, na.rm = T),
            win_prob = mean(HOME_TEAM_WINS),
            avg_fgpct_home = mean(FG_PCT_home, na.rm = T),
            avg_ftpct_home = mean(FT_PCT_home, na.rm = T),
            avg_fg3pct_home = mean(FG3_PCT_home, na.rm = T),
            avg_ast_home = mean(AST_home, na.rm = T),
            avg_reb_home = mean(REB_home, na.rm = T),
            observations = n())
games
games.df <- data.frame(games)
games.df
Y_winprob <- games.df$win_prob
X1_avgfgpct <- games.df$avg_fgpct_home
X2_avgftpct <- games.df$avg_ftpct_home
X3_avgfg3pct <- games.df$avg_fg3pct_home
X4_avgast <- games.df$avg_ast_home
X5_avgreb <- games.df$avg_reb_home
X6_avgpts <- games.df$avg_points

NBA_Home.lm <- lm(Y_winprob ~ X1_avgfgpct + X2_avgftpct + X3_avgfg3pct +X4_avgast +X5_avgreb + X6_avgpts)
NBA_Home.lm


summary(NBA_Home.lm)
```

I used dplyr to create a data frame of all the team averages in order to run a regression of win probability against the various statistics. I then did the exact same thing, but, this time, I ran the analysis with away stats:

```
games2 <- NBA.df %>%
  group_by(SEASON, TEAM_ID_away) %>%
  summarise(avg_points = mean(PTS_away, na.rm = T),
            win_probaway = 1 -  mean(HOME_TEAM_WINS),
            avg_fgpct_away = mean(FG_PCT_away, na.rm = T),
            avg_ftpct_away = mean(FT_PCT_away, na.rm = T),
            avg_fg3pct_away = mean(FG3_PCT_away, na.rm = T),
            avg_ast_away = mean(AST_away, na.rm = T),
            avg_reb_away = mean(REB_away, na.rm = T),
            observations = n())
games2.df <- data.frame(games2)
games2.df
YA_winprob <- games2.df$win_probaway
X1A_avgfgpct <- games2.df$avg_fgpct_away
X2A_avgftpct <- games2.df$avg_ftpct_away
X3A_avgfg3pct <- games2.df$avg_fg3pct_away
X4A_avgast <- games2.df$avg_ast_away
X5A_avgreb <- games2.df$avg_reb_away
X6A_avgpts <- games2.df$avg_points

NBA_Away.lm <- lm(YA_winprob ~ X1A_avgfgpct + X2A_avgftpct + X3A_avgfg3pct +X4A_avgast +X5A_avgreb + X6A_avgpts)
NBA_Away.lm
summary(NBA_Away.lm)
```

**Question**
This all checks out fine. I just do not really know what I would do to be able to combine the two to one big dataset. Rather than grouping by SEASON and TEAM AWAY/HOME ID, I want group just by SEASON and have a W/L record total for each team.

For example, I am trying to combine the two sets of data to where it'll be grouped by SEASON and just the general TEAM ID (no specification on whether they were home or away), so if the data frame has "ATL", there will also be columns that say WINS for that season and LOSSES for that same season; I do not want the HOME/ AWAY distinction, just the total. I am new to dplyr, so I do not know if there is a good way to combine the two in order to end up with no separation.

Also, being new to programming, I know that I may just simply be interpreting the data wrong, so if that is the case, feel free to help me perceive my data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this could help. Here, I separately grab all the "home"-related fields and strip that from their column names, and same for all the "away" fields. Then we get a combined double-length table where home/away is now a single field but the fields that relate to one team's isolated performance are now normalized to give one "home" row and one "away" row per game. With a bit more tweaking, you should be able to analyze the combined data once instead of doing your analysis twice.

EDIT - fixed won/loss logic to provide for both teams.

```
bind_rows(
  games %>%
    mutate(won = (HOME_TEAM_WINS == 1)) %>%
    select(1:3, 6, won, contains("HOME"), contains("home")) %>%
    rename_with(~str_remove(., "_home"), contains("home")) %>%
    mutate(home = TRUE),
  games %>%
    mutate(won = (HOME_TEAM_WINS != 1)) %>%
    select(1:3, 6, won, contains("AWAY"), contains("away")) %>%
    rename_with(~str_remove(., "_away"), contains("away")) %>%
    mutate(home = FALSE)
  )
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 50,048 x 15
   GAME_DATE_EST  GAME_ID GAME_STATUS_TEXT SEASON won   HOME_TEAM_ID    TEAM_ID   PTS FG_PCT FT_PCT FG3_PCT   AST   REB HOME_TEAM_WINS home 
   <date>           <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <lgl>        <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl> <lgl>
 1 2021-11-17    22100213 Final              2021 TRUE    1610612766 1610612766    97  0.438  0.5     0.313    30    59              1 TRUE 
 2 2021-11-17    22100214 Final              2021 TRUE    1610612765 1610612765    97  0.425  0.75    0.286    16    42              1 TRUE 
 3 2021-11-17    22100215 Final              2021 TRUE    1610612737 1610612737   110  0.506  0.833   0.351    28    40              1 TRUE 
 4 2021-11-17    22100216 Final              2021 TRUE    1610612751 1610612751   109  0.458  0.84    0.375    29    47              1 TRUE 
 5 2021-11-17    22100217 Final              2021 TRUE    1610612748 1610612748   113  0.483  0.824   0.375    29    39              1 TRUE 
 6 2021-11-17    22100218 Final              2021 FALSE   1610612752 1610612752    98  0.42   0.667   0.327    25    45              0 TRUE 
 7 2021-11-17    22100219 Final              2021 TRUE    1610612749 1610612749   109  0.46   0.708   0.324    22    52              1 TRUE 
 8 2021-11-17    22100220 Final              2021 TRUE    1610612750 1610612750   107  0.5    0.833   0.278    20    35              1 TRUE 
 9 2021-11-17    22100221 Final              2021 TRUE    1610612760 1610612760   101  0.446  0.563   0.256    18    56              1 TRUE 
10 2021-11-17    22100222 Final              2021 TRUE    1610612756 1610612756   105  0.441  0.714   0.333    27    49              1 TRUE 
# … with 50,038 more rows
```

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to help. Unfortunately I am getting an error message like so: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `won`.
i `won = (HOME_TEAM_WINS == 1)`.
x object 'HOME_TEAM_WINS' not found
i The error occurred in group 1: SEASON = 2003. Would you know how to fix this by chance?

Comment: Perhaps you are not downloading all the columns of the source file you linked to? If you don't want that column to get win info you could skip the `mutate(won = ....` rows in both sections.